# neo4j-import slower twice in version 3.1.3

Tags: neo4j

I work with version 3.0.7 and tooks in a linux server half an hour to import the files
In the same server I work with version 3.1.3 and it tooks like an hour to import the same files
It's something known?
What can I do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done some memory configuration, or is-it the default settings ?

Comment: can you share more details? what files, how did you import them what were your memory settings, etc.

Comment: defaults settings
import through neo4j-import command bigfiles edges 100 GB nodes 2 GB
I did another import with version 3.0.7 after i ran with 3.1.3 in the same server and got the same difference (twice time)